# Using PHP to organize data from forms in one location

Tags: php

A client currently has the following problem:

They have a form on their page where customers input various forms of data. The form is then submitted and e-mailed to the company. That is horribly inefficient for the person at the company who has to log all of that info, email by email.

How can we use PHP (or an even simpler solution) to collect and organize every submission into a single document?

They would like me to put all of the submitted data into an Excel spreadsheet (I am using a WordPress plugin called [Export to Excel](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/export-2-excel/), but it is not working correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to open a CSV file, put the column headers as the first line, and then keep appending lines to that files. e.g.

```
datetime, name, phone, address
01/11/2013 12:01:02, abc, 123, foo
01/11/2013 12:01:03, bar, 345, fgh
```

and so on. Create a fresh file for each day; write a cron that mails out that file every day. Recipients can directly open the csv file in excel. Optionally your cron can export the file into excel at the end of the day. The cron can be set to run at any desired frequency; remember to rotate the csv file so that you are not emailing same data again and again.

In enterprise grade applications, form submissions are written to a DB, and then a page is written that then pulls the data from the DB, displays it on screen. The page can also allow 'download as excel' function. The page usually implements some filters as well, like submitted date between so and so.